# How to populate an array till its length with some specific values from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function 
`int[ ] fill(int[ ] arr, int k, int n)` that returns an array with the length `n` and values consists of repetition of first `k` elements.

My code is:

```
class Repeat_block {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int k = 3;
    int n = 10;
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, -2, -1 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fill(arr, k, n)));

}

public static int[] fill(int[] arr, int k, int n) {
    int arr2[] = new int[n];
    if (k == 0 || n <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i <k) {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];

        }

    }

    return arr2;

}
```

}

The function should return 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1
  but it's returning 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 . I tried with so many ideas 
  but could not figure out to get the right logic. Anybody with some best ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Once `i == k`, you need to reset it to 0. Hence you need to use two loop variables.

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++, j++) {
     if (j == k) {
        j = 0;
     }
     arr2[i] = arr[j];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....that works like magic... and i understood your code too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your for-loop with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {           
  arr2[i] = arr[i % k]
}
```

Comment: @ Dan Porat thanks mate...your answer seems surprising to me... very tricky one...well I did not know that 2%3 will produce 2. Is  this a standard algorithm or you happened to do that way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static int[] fill(int[] arr, int k, int n) {
    if (k == 0 || n <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int[] ret = new int[n];
    int counter = 0;
    int value = 1;
    while (counter < n) {
        if (value > k) value = 1;
        ret[counter] = value;
        value++;
        counter++;
    }
    return ret;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it will be easy using streams and I am sure that it can be done much easier but here is my poor attempt:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int k = 3;
        int n = 10;
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 12, -2, -1 };
        fill(arr, k, n);
    }

    public static void fill(int[] arr, int k, int n) {
        String elementsToCopy = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .limit(k)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .reduce((a,b) -> a.concat(",").concat(b))
                .get();

        List<String> resultInList = Collections.nCopies(n, elementsToCopy);
        resultInList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(resultInList
                .toString()
                .replace(" ", "")
                .replace("[", "")
                .substring(0, n+n-1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for practice, I done that in Python3 :

```
def fill(arr,k,n):
    c = math.ceil(n/k)
    return (arr[0:k]*c)[0:n]
```